# SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack has a C pointer to a user-specified info.  Does that info guarantee to point to the same context object that was passed in SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback's context parameter?

```
Boolean SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback (
   SCNetworkReachabilityRef target,
   SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack callout,
   SCNetworkReachabilityContext *context
);

typedef void (*SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack)    (
   SCNetworkReachabilityRef target,
   SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags,
   void *info
);
```

[SCNetwortReachability reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress)

Answer (score 0):

It points to the info field of the context structure that you associated with that particular SCNetworkReachabilityRef.

```
typedef struct {
    CFIndex     version;
    void *      info;
    const void  *(*retain)(const void *info);
    void        (*release)(const void *info);
    CFStringRef (*copyDescription)(const void *info);
} SCNetworkReachabilityContext;
```